# How to use real DJI controller in simulator

Tags: flight-controller, recommendations, dji, simulators, dji-mini-2

I've got a DJI Mini 2 and I'm aware their official application (DJI Simulator) does not support it.

Anyway, I wonder if I can use the real Mini 2 controller in any third-part simulator.
I'm more interested in an Android app that simulate the camera view of a drone (like in real flying) rather than a desktop application (in any case I run Linux).

I tried a couple of apps that claims to support USB controller but they didn't recognized mine (for example Freerider).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transmitter needs to appear as a USB joystick to the computer. This is often displayed as 'HID' (human input device). At least, that's for desktops, I don't know if Android is the same.

I've no idea if the DJI transmitter can do this.

If not, you can buy a USB dummy RC transmitter. These used to be about \$20, but I've just checked and they seem to be around \$60 now. It could be cheaper to buy a basic real transmitter like a FlySky FS-i6

All the flight simulators I've seen have a choice of 'camera' positions. They can show you the view from the drone or the view from the ground (and often a 'chase plane' view). However they are all for race drones with fixed cameras (and LOS flying for fixed wings and helis). I don't think there are any that attempt to model the various GPS modes available on a DJI drone, or the camera gimbal.

Comment: I tried with `lsusb` on my Ubuntu machine and unfortunately the controller is not recognized. Also in `dmesg` nothing happens on USB connection. What a pity.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at simodrone app. It is however very basic.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Wiz4GMRHQw

Comment: Unfortunately it seems available only for Apple